# Is my approach for Palindrome right or is there a better way to do it?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, palindrome

The code below is for checking whether the input string is palindrome or not

```
const { argv } = require("process");

(()=>{
    var palindrom01 = palindrom01;
    
    palindrom01();

    function palindrom01(){

        let inputNum = argv[2];
        let totalLength = inputNum.length;
        let half_length = parseInt(totalLength/2);
        let flag = true; 
        
        for(let i = 0, j = (totalLength - 1); i < half_length; i++){
            if(inputNum.charAt(i) !== inputNum.charAt(j)){
                flag = false;    
                break;
            }
            j--;
        }

        console.log(`input ${inputNum} is Palinform => ${flag}`);
    }
})();
```

This is the output of the code

```
D:\> node .\palindrom.js 12321
input 12321 is Palinform => true
D:\> node .\palindrom.js 123321
input 123321 is Palinform => true
D:\> node .\palindrom.js 12345
input 12345 is Palinform => false
D:\>
```

Is Panlindrome properly implemented?
if yes, is there a way better way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a short review;

- `palindrom01` does too much

  1. it finds the input
  2. it determines whether the input is a palindrome
  3. it prints to the console
     These could be 3 different functions
- `var palindrom01 = palindrom01;` -> I guess you are trying to hoist the function to the top or something. However, you can remove this complete
- `palindrom01` is not a great function name, I would go for `isPalindrome(s)` which returns a boolean
- Most people consider the best approach a [split to an array of characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse), [concatenate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and compare to the original again
- In general I like self-executing functions, but it seems, in this case, it is overkill

This is my counter-example,

```js
function getInput(){
  return Input.value;
}

function isPalindrome(s){
  return s === s.split('').reverse().join('');
}

function showIsPalindrome(s){
  console.log( `${s} is${isPalindrome(s)?'':' not'} a palindrome` );
}

function controller(event){
  const enterKey = 13;
  if(event.keyCode === enterKey){
    showIsPalindrome(getInput());
  }
}

Input.addEventListener('keypress', controller);
```

```html
<input id='Input'></input>
```

Comment: Thanks. pls let share some websites for improving my problem solving coding skills

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/programming-challenge/info